# eliminar espacios en blanco de varios textos

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero eliminar los esapcios de varios textos con el mismo id. Pude eliminar el espacio en blanco del primer id pero el resto sigue igual. En caso de que no se pueda hacer mediante ID y si por clase entonces no hay problema porque puedo modificarlo.

```
<div id="numeroacopiar">
          01
        </div>
<div id="numeroacopiar">
          02
        </div>
<div id="numeroacopiar">
          03
        </div>
```

```
$("#numeroacopiar").text(function (index, oldText) {
    return oldText.replace(/\s+/g, '');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los `id` deben ser **UNICOS** siempre

Los algoritmos que buscan en el DOM, cuando lo hacen por id, paran al primero resultado, por eso a ti te funcia solo con el primer item

Debes usar algo que no sea una id, como por ejemplo `class`

```js
$(".numeroacopiar").text(function (index, oldText) {
    return oldText.replace(/\s+/g, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="numeroacopiar">
          01
        </div>
<div class="numeroacopiar">
          02
        </div>
<div class="numeroacopiar">
          03
        </div>
```